# How to use React.forwardRef in a class based component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React.forwardRef, but tripping over how to get it to work in a class based component (not HOC).

The docs examples use elements and functional components, even wrapping classes in functions for higher order components.

So, starting with something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5q8y5m86x) in their `ref.js` file:

```
const TextInput = React.forwardRef(
    (props, ref) => (<input type="text" placeholder="Hello World" ref={ref} />)
);
```

and instead defining it as something like this:

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { props, ref } = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ({ props, ref }));
    return <input type="text" placeholder="Hello World" ref={ref} />;
  }
}
```

or

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (<input type="text" placeholder="Hello World" ref={ref} />))
    );
  }
}
```

only working :/

Also, I know I know, ref's aren't the react way. I'm trying to use a third party canvas library, and would like to add some of their tools in separate components, so I need event listeners, so I need lifecycle methods. It may go a different route later, but I want to try this.

The docs say it's possible!

> Ref forwarding is not limited to DOM components. You can forward refs to class component instances, too.

from the [note in this section.](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components)

But then they go on to use HOCs instead of just classes.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The idea to always use the same prop for the `ref` can be achieved by proxying class export with a helper.

```
class ElemComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>
        Div has a ref
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <ElemComponent 
  innerRef={ref} {...props}
/>);
```

So basically, we are forced to have a different prop to forward ref, but it can be done under the hub. It's important that the public use it as a normal ref.

Comment: What do you do if you have your component wrapped in a HOC like React-Redux's `connect` or marterial-ui's `withStyles`?

Comment: What's the problem with `connect` or `withStyles`? You should wrap all HOCs with `forwardRef` and internally use "safe" prop to pass a ref to the lowest component in the chain.

Comment: Any insight on how to test this in Enzyme when you are using setState?

Comment: Sorry I'll need a bit more details. Not sure what is the problem exactly.

Comment: I am getting:
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @J.Hesters the solution won't work for `withStyles` because `withStyles` internally uses `innerRef`, just rename your own ref prop to something different like `containerInnerRef` and your are good to go.

Comment: @MrBr How exactly would you implement exporting with a `React.forwardRef` to a component wrapped with redux's `connect`? I am not sure what you meant by wrapping all HOCs with `forwardRef`. I've been trying to do it but still no luck. Here's how I am doing it:

`export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(<ElemComponent innerRef={ref} {...props} />)
);`

Comment: @KAYLE you are using the connect in the wrong way. `connect(...)((props) => <Elem innerRef={ref} {props}/>)`

Comment: @MrBr where does the React.forwardRef go in this?

Comment: @KAYLE as it were in your comment, just update the connect part.

Comment: @MrBr So this is what I did: `export default React.forwardRef(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )((props, ref) => <ElemComponent innerRef={ref} {...props} />)
);`
and I got this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _hocName.default) is not a function`

Comment: I have this `export default withRouter( connect(mapStateToProps, {getSimilarObj,trackObject})(Comp))` How to pass ref

Comment: Extract default export into a component variable and then wrap it with forwardRef HoC as mentioned above.

Answer (score 19):

```
class BeautifulInput extends React.Component {
  const { innerRef, ...props } = this.props;
  render() (
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
        <input ref={innerRef} {...props} />
      </div>
    )
  )
}

const BeautifulInputForwardingRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <BeautifulInput {...props} innerRef={ref}/>
));

const App = () => (
  <BeautifulInputForwardingRef ref={ref => ref && ref.focus()} />
)
```

You need to use a different prop name to forward the ref to a class. `innerRef` is commonly used in many libraries.

Comment: in your code `beautifulInputElement` is more a function rather than a React Element, it should be like this `const beautifulInputElement = <BeautifulInputForwardingRef ref={ref => ref && ref.focus()} />`

Comment: `const { innerRef, ...props } = this.props;` gives error `Identifier 'props' has already been declared.`

Answer (score 13):

Basically, this is just a HOC function. If you wanted to use it with class, you can do this by yourself and use regular props.

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <input ref={this.props.forwardRef} />
    }
}

const ref = React.createRef();
<TextInput forwardRef={ref} />
```

This pattern is used for example in `styled-components` and it's called `innerRef` there.

Comment: Using a differently-named prop like `innerRef` is completely missing the point. The goal is complete transparency: I should be able to treat a `<FancyButton>` as if it was a regular DOM element, but using styled-components approach, I need to remember that this component uses an arbitrarily-named prop for refs instead of just `ref`.

Comment: In any case, styled-components intends to [drop support for `innerRef`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1694) in favor of passing the ref to the child using `React.forwardRef`, which is what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished with a higher-order component, if you like:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

const withForwardedRef = Comp => {
  const handle = (props, ref) =>
    <Comp {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />

  const name = Comp.displayName || Comp.name
  handle.displayName = `withForwardedRef(${name})`

  return forwardRef(handle)
}

export default withForwardedRef
```

And then in your component file:

```
class Boop extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { forwardedRef } = this.props

    return (
      <div ref={forwardedRef} />
    )
  }
}

export default withForwardedRef(Boop)
```

I did the work upfront with tests & published a package for this, `react-with-forwarded-ref`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-forwarded-ref

Answer (score 5):

Incase you need to reuse this in many difference components, you can export this ability to something like `withForwardingRef`

```
const withForwardingRef = <Props extends {[_: string]: any}>(BaseComponent: React.ReactType<Props>) =>
    React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <BaseComponent {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />);

export default withForwardingRef;
```

usage:

```
const Comp = ({forwardedRef}) => (
 <input ref={forwardedRef} />
)
const EnhanceComponent = withForwardingRef<Props>(Comp);  // Now Comp has a prop called forwardedRef
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still having trouble combining `React.forwardRef()` with a HOC like react-redux `connect()` then this is how I got it to work:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <MyComponent innerRef={ref} {...props} />)
);
```