# Fowarded ref is null

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from this thread: [How to use React.forwardRef in a class based component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526461/how-to-use-react-forwardref-in-a-class-based-component)
I also went through the docs quite carefully, but my ref forwarding simply doesn't seem to work.

**Component to create ref:**

```
class TextEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        this.editor = createRef();
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.editor) // -> This is always empty
        return (
            <BaseEditor ref={this.editor}/>
        );
    }
}
```

**Component to receive the ref:**

```
class BaseEditor extends Component<Props> {

    render() {
        return (
            <Editor ref={this.props.innerRef}/>
        );
    }
}

const BaseEditorForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => (
    <BaseEditor {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseEditorForwardRef)
```

I feel like everything is where it should. Yet the ref does not exist within `TextEditor` if I'm forwarding the ref without using `React.forwardRef` everything works.

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the ref to the already redux-connected component(i didn't try it with redux, but with another HOC, i hope it works for you):

```
class BaseEditor extends Component<Props> {

    render() {
        return (
            <Editor ref={this.props.innerRef}/>
        );
    }
}

const Connected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseEditor)


const BaseEditorForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => (
    <Connected {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));

export default BaseEditorForwardRef
```

Comment: fantastic, this works. I'm not exactly sure why though. The other HOC should just pass down every other prop as `{ ...props }`including the ref. Hm ...

Comment: I'm not sure why either, but remember that refs aren't props. I'm glad it works.

Comment: :-) yes, refs aren't props - true. But when forwarding them, you pin them to a prop (in my case innerRef). InnerRef in turn should be passed down from within `connect` to its children as part of the `{ ... props}` ... but yeah, it works - so no questions asked.

Comment: `connect` would create an entirely new Component with its own `ref`. However, React Redux actually provides a `forwardRef` option for `connect`. I think this would work too. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#forwardref-boolean

Answer (score 0):

`connect` would create an entirely new Component with its own `ref`. However, React Redux actually provides a `forwardRef` option for `connect` which should work allow for forwarding the ref.

> If {forwardRef : true} has been passed to connect, adding a ref to the connected wrapper component will actually return the instance of the wrapped component.

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#forwardref-boolean