# How to set reference in a wrapped component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.jsx

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Main {...this.props} ref={this.props.setRef}>
</Provider>
```

I want to set ref in the  component. I want to call the method of the main component in my service file using reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use React.forwardRef in a class based component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526461/how-to-use-react-forwardref-in-a-class-based-component)

Answer (score 0):

`ref`s only work with DOM element, they don't work with React component. However, if you want a ref to one DOM element rendered by Main, it's possible to do it using forwardRef