# How to call a function from outside a class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button to upload files. I have used a custom toolbar. My problem is I want to call a function from outside the class. The function which I need to call is declared inside the class. Is there a way to do this? (The ActionButton which I have used here is a reusable component).`insertFile` is the function and I want call `onFileChange` inside that insertFile function.

```
AddTicket.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import { Form, FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
import ActionButton from "./../../components/ButtonComponent";
import * as Icon from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const CustomAttachment = () => (
  <span>
    <Icon.Paperclip />
  </span>
);

const CustomList = () => (
  <span>
    <Icon.ListUl />
  </span>
);

const CustomLink = () => (
  <span>
    <Icon.Link />
  </span>
);

function insertFile() {
  console.log("File Icon");
  // this.onFileChange();
}

const CustomToolbar = () => (
  <div id="toolbar">
    <button className="ql-file">
      <CustomAttachment />
    </button>
  </div>
);

class AddTicket extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorHtml: "",
      selectedFile: null,
    };
  }


  onFileChange = (event) => {
    // Update the state
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  onFileUpload = () => {
    // Create an object of formData
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Update the formData object
    formData.append(
      "myFile",
      this.state.selectedFile
      // this.state.selectedFile.name
    );

    // Details of the uploaded file
    console.log(this.state.selectedFile);

    // Request made to the backend api
    // Send formData object
    axios.post("api/uploadfile", formData);
  };

  static modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: "#toolbar",

      handlers: {
        file: insertFile,
      },
    },
  };

  static formats = [
    "header",
    "font",
    "size",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strike",
    "blockquote",
    "list",
    "bullet",
    "indent",
    "link",
    "image",
    "color",
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popup-box">
        <div className="box">
          {/* <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>
            x
          </span> */}
          <Form
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            style={{ paddingLeft: 30, paddingTop: 50 }}
          >
            <Row style={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}>
              <Col sm={11} xs={11} md={11}>
                <h1>Add new ticket </h1>
              </Col>
              <Col onClick={this.props.handleClose} m={1} xs={1} md={1}>
                <h1 className="close-icon">X </h1>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <FormGroup>
              <Row style={{ marginBottom: "25px" }}>
                <Col sm={2}>
                  <h4>Description</h4>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={9}>
                  <div className="editor-wrapper">
                    <div className="editor-container">
                      <div className="text-editor">
                        <CustomToolbar />
                        <ReactQuill
                          value={this.state.editorHtml}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                          modules={AddTicket.modules}
                          formats={AddTicket.formats}
                        />
                        <div>Test</div>
                        <div>
                          <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>

            <Row>
              <Col sm={2}></Col>
              <Col>
                <ActionButton text="Send" />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddTicket;
```

Comment: that's not possible, you should pass the function to the click handler of your action button, right?

Comment: You can use your  React.forwardRef with your component, it will pass an instance ref of your component on another component, then you can call required functions from the ref component. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526461/how-to-use-react-forwardref-in-a-class-based-component