# How to scroll to a component from another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, components

I have a form that, on submission displays the results of the form, but more importantly, scrolls to a component that shows the results. I am stuck trying to pass in refs and forward refs. All of the demos I've seen have been of components in the same file. My setup is as follows:

The `App.js` holds two components– `Form.js` which submits the form and `Results.js` which displays the results of the form submission. The `Results.js` component is further down the page so I want to scroll to that component once the user clicks enter on the form.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-ride-slq001?file=/src/Form.js) that demonstrates my setup.

Here is the same code on here:

```js
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import Form from "./Form";
import Results from "./Results";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <Results />
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
// Form.js
import { forwardRef, useState } from "react";

const Form = forwardRef(({ onScroll }, ref) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onScroll();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="tall">
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
});

export default Form;
```

```js
// Results.js

import { useRef } from "react";
export default function Results() {
  const resultsRef = useRef();

  function handleScrollToResults() {
    resultsRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  return (
    <div onScroll={handleScrollToResults}>
      <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Few things to be corrected.

1. `Results` component should forward the ref, not to the `Form` component.

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const Results = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Results;
```

2. `Form` component should receive the ref to `Results` as a prop (`resultRef`).

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Form = ({ resultRef }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    resultRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="tall">
      <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

3. Root component should create the `ref` using `useRef` and use it as below. Notice that `Form` is using the `resultRef` while `Results` is instantiating it.

```
import "./styles.css";
import Form from "./Form";
import Results from "./Results";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const resultRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <Form resultRef={resultRef} />
      <Results ref={resultRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Scroll Component (forked)]

Comment: hi! This was really helpful. Can we do this without using hooks. Like in class components.

Comment: @risingStark, did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526461/how-to-use-react-forwardref-in-a-class-based-component) ?