# How can I pass a reference of a mapview to another component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a map view, and in another componenet, I would like to be able to have a function that animates that mapview. That function would need a reference to my map view. How can I access my maps reference inside another component?

I have a [snack expo that reproduces my problem exactly here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/pass-reference-to-component) as well as some code below. **Please note which files are classes and which are functions.** The files are too big in my projects, I do not want to change them

EDIT: Could I use some sort of state library such as Context to store the ref?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Map/>
      <AnimateMapButton/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I cant access this._map for obvious reasons. How can I access this?

```
export default class AnimateMapButton extends React.Component {

  goToLocation = () => {
    this._map.animateToRegion({
      latitude: 103.1561,
      longitude: -47.1651,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0025,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0025,
    })
  }

  render() {
  return (
      <View style={{height: 75, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', top: 100}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToLocation()}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, }}>Click to animate the map</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
}
}
```

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView 
        style={styles.map}
        ref={map => this._map = map}
       />
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `React.forwardRef` in such scenarios.

map.js

```
export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        ref={ref}
        style={styles.map}
      />
    </View>
  );
})
```

*****animatemapbutton.js*****

```
export default class AnimateMapButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
  return (
      <View style={{height: 75, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', top: 100}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onGotoLocation()}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, }}>Click to animate the map</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
}
}
```

***App.js***

```
 export default function App() {
       const _mapRef = React.createRef();
    
        goToLocation = () => {
        _mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
          latitude: 103.1561,
          longitude: -47.1651,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0025,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0025,
        })
      }
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Map ref={_mapRef}/>
          <AnimateMapButton onGotoLocation={goToLocation} />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work. I really need Map to be a class.

Comment: @guts716., You can do that as well using forwardRef. Please add this snippet inside map.js.

`class Map extends React.Component {
  render(){ return ( <View style={styles.container}><MapView ref={this.props.innerRef} style={styles.map}/></View>);}}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Map innerRef={ref} {...props}/>)`

For more information about forwardRef, Please check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526461/how-to-use-react-forwardref-in-a-class-based-component) once

Comment: Very interesting! No idea this even existed. I am going to check it out once I get home from work. Should reward you your points then! Thank you for the help Gavara.

Comment: I edited my example here. The button is not reacting to anything. Any idea why? https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/pass-reference-to-component

Comment: I have just downloaded your code and strangely I could able to tap the **Click to animate the map** button. the Map is moving in some directions.

Comment: Ah yes, I am not sure why it was not working for me. It is now. Could you look at the link I sent above one more time? Your answer created a new question for me that I have here.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453756/combining-two-functions-that-wrap-my-class-component

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a combination of reference and event callback method in the root component like this -

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const mapRef = React.useRef();

  const goToLocation = () => {
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Map mapRef={mapRef} />
      <AnimateMapButton goToLocation={goToLocation} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

animatemapbutton.js

```
export default function Animatemapbutton({ goToLocation }) {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ height: 75, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', top: 100 }}
        onPress={() => goToLocation()}
      >
        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, }}>Click to animate the map</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

map.js

```
export default function Map({ mapRef }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.map}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You changed classes to functions. How can I implement this with the according classes and functions I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: Map and AnimateButton should both be classes, not functions