# Combining two functions that wrap my class component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-forwardref

I have a class component that is wrapped by a function in order to pass it my theme from useContext. I have now discovered I would like to wrap my class component in a fowardRef as well. That leaves me with two functions at the end of my Map class component that looks like so. I also have a [snack example here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/pass-reference-to-component).

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView ref={this.props.innerRef} style={styles.map} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default function(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <Map {...props} theme={theme} />;
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Map innerRef={ref} {...props} />
));
```

Now this is not allowed because of the two exports, so I tried what you see below.

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView ref={this.props.innerRef} style={styles.map} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default function(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <MapForwardingRef {...props} theme={theme} />;
}

const MapForwardingRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Map innerRef={ref} {...props}/>
));
```

However this resulted in, null is not an object, this.props.innerRef.

**How can I pass it innerRef as well as the theme?**

Answer (score 1):

you should only have one default export so it should be something like

```
const ThemeProvider = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const theme = useTheme();

  return <Map {...props} theme={theme} innerRef={ref}/>;

})

export default ThemeProvider
```

Comment: The reason I dont convert is because in my overall project, it is a pretty big file already. Would be a lot

Comment: then u can ignore the 2nd part.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting the error in this example?https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/pass-reference-to-component
It is saying the ref is empty

Comment: see my example where i use `innerRef={ref}`

Comment: That is using that example. Did you click the link?

Comment: yes. in your link you are using `ref={ref}` in `map.js`. In order to use `props.innerRef`, you need to pass `innerRef` in the component.  You can either do that within the ThemeProvider component, or when you are using ThemeProvider component.