# Why doesn't const { innerRef, ...props } = this.props; grab a refrence to this.props.innerRef in react ref forwarding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

After reading forwarding refs from react legacy [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) and following the examples from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51526461/3429430) on using ref forwarding on classes, I tried to create a working example as following:

```js
class Card extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    //after three seconds focus myRef
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.myRef);
      this.myRef.current.focus();
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return <FancybtnWthRef ref={this.myRef} txt="random"/>;
  }
}

//Fancybtn class based componenet with ref forwarding

class Fancybtn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { innerRef, ...props2 } = this.props;
    console.log(innerRef, this.props.innerRef); //doesn't get live binding to this.props.innerRef
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="fancy-btn" ref={this.innerRef} {...this.props2}>
        {this.props.txt}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const FancybtnWthRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Fancybtn {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
});




ReactDOM.render(
  <Card />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

On the other hand, if I grab the `this.props.innerRef` object directly for button, then it works:

```js
class Card extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    //after three seconds focus myRef
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.myRef);
      this.myRef.current.focus();
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return <FancybtnWthRef ref={this.myRef} txt="random"/>;
  }
}

//Fancybtn class based componenet with ref forwarding

class Fancybtn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { innerRef, ...props2 } = this.props;
    console.log(innerRef, this.props.innerRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="fancy-btn" ref={this.props.innerRef} {...this.props2}>
        {this.props.txt}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const FancybtnWthRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Fancybtn {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
});





ReactDOM.render(
  <Card />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In plain javascript destructuring gets live binding of objects as following:

```
var obj = {x:1, obj2: {y: 33}}
const {x, obj2} = obj;
obj2.y = 44;
cconsole.log(obj.obj2.y); //gives 44
```

Using the same argument why doesn't `const { innerRef, ...props } = this.props;` grab the actual `this.props.innerRef` for the `button`?

Comment: `this.innerRef` does not exist and is never assigned. `const { innerRef, ... }` defines and assigns a _local_ constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const { innerRef, ...props2 } = this.props;` does correctly get the `innerRef` property from `props`. However, this creates two **local** variables. It does not set the actual `innerRef` property on the instance itself. Thus, `this.innerRef` is `undefined` and passing that as the ref to the `<button>` has no effect. Note that unlike other languages like Java, accessing a variable without using `this` will not attempt to look up that variable in the fields of the enclosing class instance.

You would have to manually assign the `innerRef` to the instance to see it work:

```js
this.innerRef = innerRef;
```

Or, to destructure the properties onto `this`, you can rename the property like so:

```js
({ innerRef: this.innerRef, ...this.props2 } = this.props);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I was trying to do `const { this.innerRef, props2 } = this.props;` or `{ this.innerRef, props2 } = this.props;` but it gives _Unexpected keyword 'this'_.

Comment: @user31782 I've updated my answer. See the last part for how to destructure with `this`.